# horizontal scroll on clicking button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I want to horizontally scroll a div by clicking on the button Left and Right but it is not working

```
$('#left').live('click' , function(){
$('#myDiv').scrollLeft(300)

})
$('#right').live('click' , function(){
$('#myDiv').scrollLeft(-300)

})
```

​
How can I scroll a div by a bytton click. I also want to remove the scroll bar

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ranasaani/57wdH/39/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to get rid of the scroll bars, why don't you just alter the CSS of the cropped content (i.e. its `margin-left`)?

Give the wrapping `div` a `overflow:hidden` and use the following JS:

```
$('#left').click(function(){
    $('#myDiv').css('margin-left','-300px');
});
$('#right').click(function(){
    $('#myDiv').css('margin-left','0');
});
```

Would look like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/57wdH/54/)**.

​

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/57wdH/78/)

i used css and margins for scroll, overflow hidden to hide the bar, float to align the pictures and changed some css...